# How to change these Putty commands into Centos ones?

Tags: centos, putty

wget http://security.debian.org/debian-security/pool/updates/main/m/mysql-5.1/libmysqlclient16_5.1.73-1_i386.deb

mkdir mysql32

dpkg --extract libmysqlclient*deb mysql32

mv mysql32/usr/lib/* /usr/lib32

Comment: What's your question? These aren't "putty" commands. Putty is a tool to talk to an SSH host, like say a CentOS machine. So, if you get Putty to connect to CentOS, then when you type you're running the commands on CentOS.

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to do, but I am 99% certain you are going about it the wrong way.  It is extremely unlikely that you need a Debian security patch for a Centos system.

Answer (score 1):

The commands you've given are for Debian based linux systems, such as Debian and Ubuntu, and are not "putty" specific as Rich pointed out. CentOS is built from Red Hat/Fedora linux, so its commands will differ.

The `wget` command will work the same, though you may need to install wget first with `yum install wget`.

You'll need a different resource to download MySQL from, as that link goes to a `.deb` package, which is for Debian linux. You'll want a package of the file extension `.rpm`

The `mkdir` command is the same, so is `mv`

Instead of `dpkg`, you would use `rpm` with a few command line arguments for that package. To figure out what arguments you need to use, you can just run `rpm` from the command line and it'll show usage instructions

Edit: If you just want to install MySQL Server, you can just use `yum install mysql`